Hibernate 5 Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
I am migrating application to Hibernate 5 and I am getting an error:
ERROR repository.legacy.HibernateSessionManager - "Initial SessionFactory creation failed"
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager$DiskStorePath.<init>(DiskStorePathManager.java:331)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)

I am using hibernate
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

with:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

in hibernate.cfg.xml I have:
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>

I found similar questions but noone got this: Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
What is the problem here?

I would suggest to put a breakpoint inside java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively (I know is not your class but with the IDE you should be able to put a breakpoint. This way you will be able to see which is the file that is trying to create. --> The error is pretty clear the OS it not giving you permissions to create the file.

@Joan, this method is native so I can just see @Override     public native boolean createFileExclusively(String path)             throws IOException;

And this one: DiskStorePathManager.java:331?

It seems like ehcache is trying to use the disk. You can see the sourcode on: https://github.com/svn2github/ehcache/blob/master/trunk/ehcache/ehcache-core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/DiskStorePathManager.java

This is the default path:
public static String getDefaultPath() {
return Env.JAVA_IO_TMPDIR.substitute(Env.JAVA_IO_TMPDIR.variable);
}
As per the class: https://github.com/svn2github/ehcache/blob/master/trunk/ehcache/ehcache-core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/config/DiskStoreConfiguration.java

Thanks @Joan for help. Problem was that in Tomcat configuration

I put path which was not accessible by application. After change to other path file was created and I don't see Access denied error
